# How to create n-dimensional test data for cluster analysis?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working on a C++ implementation of k-means and therefore I need n-dimensional test data. For the beginning 2D points are sufficient, since they can be visualized easily in a 2D image, but I'd finally prefer a general approach that supports n dimensions.

There was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050209/1809463) here on stackoverflow, which proposed concatenating sequential vectors of random numbers with different offsets and spreads, but I'm not sure how to create those, especially without including a 3rd party library.

Below is the method declaration I have so far, it contains the parameters which should vary. But the can be changed, if necessary - with the exception of `data`, it needs to be a pointer type since I'm using OpenCL.

```
auto populateTestData(float** data, uint8_t dimension, uint8_t clusters, uint32_t elements) -> void;
```

---

Another problem that came to my mind was the efficient detection/avoidance of collisions when generating random  numbers. Couldn't that be a performance bottle neck, e.g. if one's generating 100k numbers in a domain of 1M values, i.e. if the relation between generated numbers and number space isn't small enough?

---

**QUESTION**
How can I efficiently create n-dimensional test data for cluster analysis? What are the concepts I need to follow?

Comment: Do you have a fixed n or does it vary during runtime?

Comment: There are several n in one program run, since I'm starting the algorithm multiple times. But they don't vary during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use c++11 (or boost) random stuff to create clusters, but it's a bit of work.

1. [`std::normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) can generate univariate normal distributions with zero mean.
2. Using 1. you can sample from a normal vector (just create an *n* dimensional vector of such samples).
3. If you take a vector *n* from 2. and output *A n + b*, then you've transformed the center *b* away + modified by *A*. (In particular, for 2 and 3 dimensions it's easy to build *A* as a rotation matrix.) So, repeatedly sampling 2. and performing this transformation can give you a sample centered at *b*.
4. Choose *k* pairs of *A, b*, and generate your *k* clusters.

---

**Notes**

- You can generate different clustering scenarios using different types of *A* matrices. E.g., if *A* is a non-length preserving matrix multiplied by a rotation matrix, then you can get "paraboloid" clusters (it's actually interesting to make them wider along the vectors connecting the centers).
- You can either generate the "center" vectors *b* hardcoded, or using a distribution like used for the *x* vectors above (perhaps uniform, though, using [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/)).

Comment: What are the requirements for matrix A? It should preserve length I guess. And how can I construct uniformily distributed vectors *b*?

Comment: @mike See notes above.

Comment: Thx, I accepted your answer. ...And once again linear algebra proved to be useful :)