# Looking for handy way of simulating data for cluster analysis based on predefined noise parameters

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, simulation

I'm looking for a handy way in Matlab to simulate a dataset in an N-dimensional space to test a set of cluster validation criteria I have worked on and see if they are any good.

The data I usually work with are highly dimensional (cross correlation matrix N by N for ~50K features for each N) and hence I'm not only looking for random data with clear boundaries. I want a sort of noise (or overlap) parameter that I can manipulate to see at which point do my clustering method fail to get the right answer I have.

There was a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049081/how-to-generate-a-clusterable-dataset-in-matlab/17050209#17050209) that is based on simply concatenating sequential vectors of random numbers with predefined offsets and spreads and it's great but I want to expand on that answer for a more controlled simulation.

For example, here is the code I wrote (based on the answer in the link above -- with more stuff)

```
N = [10,10,50];     % observations per cluster
D = 2;              % dimensions; set to 2 for visualization
mean=[0,25,80];     % mean of each cluster
dev=[5,10,60];      % spread around the mean of each cluster

DataSet=[];
Groups=[];
for i=1:length(N),
    DataSet = [DataSet;... 
        mean(i)+dev(i)*randn(N(i),D)];
    Groups = [Groups;...
        i*ones(N(i),1)];
end

plot(DataSet(Groups==1,1),DataSet(Groups==1,2),'ro', ...
DataSet(Groups==2,1),DataSet(Groups==2,2),'bo',...
DataSet(Groups==3,1),DataSet(Groups==3,2),'mo')
```

and it should give this plot of the 3 clusters

[image]

This is cool but how to I define overlap (and maybe other noise parameters) in a systematic way ?

See also this [R package that simulate Gaussian distributions based on overlap parameters and other cool stuff](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v51/i12/paper)

Any ideas?